# Quitar redirección en wordpress

Tags: wordpress, redirección, dominio

**Buenas, vengo a pedir una mano con Wordpress.**

Comento un problema que no entiendo como resolver.

Tengo mi sitio web *midominio.com*, que al ingresarlo al navegador me hace un redir agregando un código del tipo = ***?v=87b3b13398e9***

[image: Ejemplo real]

No encuentro opciones en el bakoffice de WP para quitarlo.
No vi nada en la base de datos a simple vista que lo agregue.
Y el .htacces me muestra esto:

```
# HTTPS forced by SG-Optimizer
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
# END HTTPS
SetEnv PHPRC /home/customer/www/maldonadoonline.uy/public_html/php.ini
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
# Wordfence WAF
<Files ".user.ini">
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        Require all denied
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
    </IfModule>
</Files>
# END Wordfence WAF
```

Finalmente, no he dado con la infomración que me explique la lógica que hace que eso suceda.
Nose si viene del wordpress o de ajustes del servidor mismo.

**¿Le paso antes a alguien?** Porque me esta matando la puntuacion en *Google PageSpeed Insight*
Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me respondieron en el foro de Wordpress:
https://es.wordpress.org/support/topic/quitar-redireccion-de-dominio-com-a-dominiov87b3b13398e9/#post-12204192

El problema se debe a un ajuste en el Woocommerce.
En el menu de ajustes de woocommerce, en «Ubicación del cliente por defecto» dobo seleccionar «Geolocalizar» y deja de agregarme ese código extra.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).